# Can mass transfer occur without a concentration difference? (analogous to the question, can energy transfer occur without a temperature difference?)

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, diffusion, convection, transport-phenomena

The driving force for diffusion of mass is a concentration gradient. However, mass can be transported both in a diffusive and a convective (due to the flow of a fluid) way. By definition, the combined mass (or molar) flux of a species i is the sum of the diffusive flux contribution and the convective flux contribution (where v is the average velocity of the mixture and j is the diffusive mass flux):

***n***<sub>i</sub>= ***j***<sub>i</sub> + ρ<sub>i</sub>***v***

Also, the diffusive mass (or molar flux) can be expressed by Fick's First Law, which says that the diffusive flux is proportional to the concentration gradient.

My doubt is: can there be any mass transfer of a species without a concentration gradient?, From the definition of the combined flux, I notice that as long as there is a velocity 'v', there will be a mass transfer, regardless of the existence of a concentration gradient. Is this correct?, if so, what would be the benefit of talking about this type of mass transfer, if any?

The case of energy transfer is analogous to my original question of mass transfer, because in the case of energy heat transfer, the driving force for heat conduction is a temperature gradient. If the fluid is moving, but there is no temperature gradient, clearly there wouldn't be any heat transfer regardless of the convection effects. Also, there wouldn't be any kind of energy transfer if the species flowing is the same (no concentration difference), because there is no difference in heat capacity anywhere. Obviously there could be energy transfer by viscous heating, but it is safe to neglect that at low to moderate velocities.

Comment: Steady flow of an incompressible fluid does not involve a concentration gradient. Energy transfer by heat requires a temperature difference. Energy transfer by work does not.

Comment: A uniform gravitational field uniformly accelerates matter, causing mass transfer without a concentration difference in the accelerating system. You could also consider the acceleration of charges in an electric field. Is this the kind of thing you're asking about?